# How to run docker with a blend file from a ftp site

Tags: docker, ftp, blender

I have manage to run this command in Docker:
**$ docker run --rm -v d:/temp/test:/media/ ikester/blender /media/blendfile.blend -o /media/frame_### -f 1**
But I want to run it from a ftp site instead of "d:/temp/test" 
As I see it I should replace "**d:/temp/test**" with someting else, but what?
Or should I do it in some other way?